# How do I read server data from a Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Store::File from another app?

Tags: perl, session, catalyst

I am running two applications on my server. The first is a Catalyst app, configured to use the [`Session`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aSession) / [`Session::State::Cookie`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aSession%3a%3aState%3a%3aCookie) / [`Session::Store::File`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aSession%3a%3aStore%3a%3aFile) suite of plugins to save some session state on the server side.

The other app is in Perl, but it's not Catalyst. I want the server-side session data from the Catalyst app to be available to the other app.

In the second app, I can load the client-side cookies and find the relevant session id for the Catalyst app, but after that I'm stuck. I don't know how to map the session id to a file name. For example, I have a session id `de079f151917d184219ef357f5298d0da478e015`, but the data for that session is only found in a file named `fc1f6f651a2313c4081bcfef679061be35de40b7`. How is the non-Catalyst app supposed to know how to find that file? (My follow up question would be how is the non-Catalyst app supposed to read that file, but I can cross that bridge when I get to it).

Is there an easier way to do this with a different storage scheme like [`Session::Store::DBIC`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aSession%3a%3aStore%3a%3aDBIC) or [`Session::Store::FastMmap`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aSession%3a%3aStore%3a%3aFastMmap)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Session::Store::File` uses [Cache::FileCache](https://metacpan.org/module/Cache%3a%3aFileCache). Simply instantiate a `Cache::FileCache` with a `cache_root` corresponding to where your app puts its session data, then use `$cache->get("session:$sessid")` to get the session data for a given `$sessid`, and if you need it, use `$cache->get("expires:$sessid")` to get the expiry time so that you can ignore a session if its expiration is before `time()`.

Comment: Thank you @hobbs, this answer saved me hours of further research. I also needed to set the `namespace` parameter in the `Cache::FileCache` constructor, which took a little trial and error to get right.

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible I would switch the session store to database, no need to search for files then.

Hope that helps.